# Does XAML design mode support more color than code view?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, visual-studio-2010, colors

While working with SilverLight using Visual Studio 10, I found that in design mode XAML allows a wide plethora of colors. For ex. Lime is a valid color in XAML.

```
<LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
  <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0" />
  <GradientStop Color="Lime"  Offset="1" />
```

While working with code though, I found that Lime and many other colors are missing...

```
GradientStop blueGS = new GradientStop(); blueGS.Color = Colors.Lime;
```

What am I missing? Both of these colors belong to System.Windows.Media.Colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colors(VS.95).aspx) for `System.Windows.Media.Colors` (Silverlight version):

> XAML Usage for Colors
>  You cannot instantiate objects from this
>   managed class in XAML, but you can use
>   its static properties to provide
>   property values in XAML. **There are
>   additional named colors that can be
>   specified in XAML, but these are not
>   backed by static property values of
>   Colors**.

So, for whatever reason, it looks like you're effectively right; you can refer to more "named" colors in XAML than you can in the codebehind.

Also, you can always use the [`Color.FromArgb`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color.fromargb(VS.95).aspx) method in your code:

```
Color lime = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00);
```

Comment: Thanks... But the main question still remains unanswered, why is it so?

Comment: Agreed; I hadn't noticed this before and now am wondering the same thing. MSDN states it quite matter-of-factly, but without any explanation as to why.